# How to change function in order to accept different types of files?

Tags: php

I have this code which helps me creeating a JPEG image, now, what I need is to create is an image, PNG JPG, or whatever it is!

I have made some modifications and here is the last result:

```
function tamano_nuevo_foto($im_or, $ancho_nv, $dir_nv) {
    $ext   = pathinfo($im_or, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $datos = getimagesize($im_or);

    $ancho = $datos[0];

    $alto = $datos[1];

    if ($ancho > $ancho_nv) { //Si la imagen no lelga al máximo no la tocamos.
        $prop    = $alto / $ancho;
        $alto_nv = round($ancho_nv * $prop); //Sacamos la nueva altura
    } else {

        $ancho_nv = $ancho;

        $alto_nv = $alto;
    }

    $im_nv = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_nv, $alto_nv);

    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
    switch ($ext) {
        case 'jpg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($im_or);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($im_or);
            break;
        default:
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
    }
    imagedestroy($im_nv);
}
```

While the original code is:

```
function tamano_nuevo_foto($im_or, $ancho_nv, $dir_nv) {
    $img   = imagecreatefromstring($im_or);
    $datos = getimagesize($im_or);
    $ancho = $datos[0];
    $alto  = $datos[1];
    if ($ancho > $ancho_nv) { //Si la imagen no lelga al máximo no la tocamos.
        $prop    = $alto / $ancho; /* Calculo la proporcion entre la or y la nv (lo miltiplicamos por mil para evitar problemas con decimales */
        $alto_nv = round($ancho_nv * $prop); //Sacamos la nueva altura
    } else {
        $ancho_nv = $ancho;
        $alto_nv  = $alto;
    }
    $im_nv    = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_nv, $alto_nv);
    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
    imagejpeg($im_nv, $dir_nv);
    imagedestroy($im_nv);
}
```

The function creates like this:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetPath =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath);
$targetFile =  $targetPath . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
tamano_nuevo_foto($tempFile, 800, $targetFile);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now done with the formatting, could you please take a look at my question? :)

Comment: Yes, the new formated code, the new function i\ve created, it won't create an image.. there shows no error but no image is created, i made some modifications from the original code, but i don't know what i did wrong!

Comment: Yes, i mean i explained why i modified the code, in order to be able to create different types of images, but it doesn't work the way i have put it! and i wonder where  might be wrong!

Comment: I wonder if you need all those functions (`imagecreatefrom[x]`) defined separately, or if you can modify the one that works to accept an extension.

Comment: yes, good point, but i could only understand it to be like this.. i don't know how to modify it otherwise..

Comment: If `imagejpeg($im_nv, $dir_nv)` was working before, just modify it by adding an optional parameter, `$ext = ""` to the function definition. Then based on the extension, create the image appropriately.

Comment: Hm please, could you just tell me how to do it? because i'm not understanding.. a piece of code as demonstration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you wanted like this:

```
function tamano_nuevo_foto($im_or, $width_nv, $dir_nv) {
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($im_or);

    $x_ratio = $width_nv / $width; 
    if($width <= $width_nv) { 
        $width_nv = $width; 
        $height_nv = $height; 
    } else { 

        $height_nv = ceil($height * $x_ratio);
    } 

    $im_nv = imagecreatetruecolor($width_nv, $height_nv);
    switch ($type) {
        case '3':
            imagealphablending($im_nv, false);
            imagesavealpha($im_nv, true); 

            $im_or = imagecreatefrompng($im_or);
            imagealphablending($im_or, true);

            header("Content-Type: image/png");
            imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $im_or, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_nv, $height_nv, $width, $height);
            imagepng($im_nv, $dir_nv);
            break;
        case '1':
            $im_or = imagecreatefromgif($im_or);
            header("Content-Type: image/gif");
            imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $im_or, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_nv, $height_nv, $width, $height);
            imagegif($im_nv, $dir_nv);
            break;
        default:
            $im_or = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $im_or, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_nv, $height_nv, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($im_nv, $dir_nv, 100);
    }


    imagedestroy($im_nv);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when i insert a png file it will upload a black one.. i mean it doesn't work with png's

Comment: I tried this and, hmm this won't recognize the extension, please let me tell you if i get the extension path ok!

Comment: the $im_or equals to this:         $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

Comment: yes please, also, let me update the question in order for you to see what creates the function!

Comment: I have updated my question, i guess i'm doing some error when finding the extension of the file..

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work even for transparent png's

Comment: Ah tears of joy stream down my face :D:D:D
THANK YOU!
One last question please!
will it have any problem if the png extension should be PNG, OR JPG i mean with uppercases?

Comment: doesn't matter. it's best lowercase, i guess. For the sake of nice formatting.

Comment: Oh unfortunately :( it has a little issue, it doesn't do the resize on proportion as before, i mean ig i resize the width 600px, it won't resize the height in proportion..

Comment: Could you please, please, check why it doesn't take the automatic resize?

Comment: i guess i understand what it is:
here, function tamano_nuevo_foto($im_or, $height_nv, $dir_nv) {
instead of height_nv i guess it's supposed to be width, from the original function i mean :)
could you please modify it... i wouldn't be able to do it!

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake, corrected now, it should constrain proportions.

Comment: hey thanks :) it takes proportions, but you make it take the height proortion, i mean they should be resized based on their width...in the function, there shoould be width_nv instead of height_nv :)

Comment: please, this is the last time i disturb you :)

Comment: yeah, there is this little problem :D, it resizes the height and width together, for example, if i set width:600 px even hight goes 600 px, before when you had set the fnction in proportion with the height, it worked :)

Comment: ups, sorry, I'm working on something else. solved. It should be ok

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks :)
you saved me from a long night :)
thanks! again "_

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're using the `$img` variable before you've created the image resource:

```
    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
    //^^ using $img 
    switch ($ext)
    {//creating img here...
        case 'jpg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($im_or);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($im_or);
            break;
        default:
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
    }
```

Just move the `imagecopyresampled` down, right after the switch. BTW, that switch can be written a lot less bulky:

```
    switch ($ext)
    {//creating img here...
        case 'png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($im_or);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($im_or);
            break;
        default://no cases for jpg or jpeg means default, which creates from jpeg
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
```

If you want to keep those `jpeg` cases for some reason, no need to write the same code twice, thanks to fall-through:

```
    switch ($ext)
    {//creating img here...
        case 'jpeg':
            //you can even add some code specifically for the jpeg
            // extention, that will not be executed if the extention is jpg
            //if you omit the break at the end, the next case will be executed, too 
        case 'jpg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
        break;
        case 'png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($im_or);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($im_or);
            break;
        default://no cases for jpg or jpeg means default, which creates from jpeg
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
```